# How to solve this issue in Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shared_preferences:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':shared_preferences:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve project :shared_preferences_macos.
> Required by:
> project :shared_preferences
> > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :shared_preferences_macos:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

> Could not resolve project :shared_preferences_web.

Required by:
project :shared_preferences
> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :shared_preferences_web:
- None of the consumable configurations have attributes.[image]

Comment: Pls attach your `pubspec.yaml` file..

Comment: it is there already

Comment: No, you have a screen shot with nearly illegible colors, not something we can copy/paste to our own computer and try to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is got solved by upgrading Flutter SDK to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`shared_preferences: 0.5.7+3`, don't use ^

copy paste that in your pubspec.yaml

or go to android studio > file > Invalidate Caches / Restart